# getting error like DefaultJwtSignatureValidator cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, validation, jwt, access-token, signature

While valodating the signature of jwt token Im getting the above error for this line

```
DefaultJwtSignatureValidator validator = new DefaultSignatureValidatore(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secretkeyspec)
```

Is `Defaultjwtsignaturevalidator` a java file that we need to create separately or do we need to import the jar?  If we need to write can someone provide the `Defaultjwtsignaturevalidator` Java file

I need to validate the JWT token which is signed with the HS256 algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your dependency does not have the runtime property

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope> <--- REMOVE THIS
    </dependency>
```